# Reading a string column in xlsx with date and time values

Tags: r, datetime, xlsx, posixct, posixlt

I am reading a .xlsx file using R. One of the columns is called "Date" and it has the following format: "20/10/2014  12:00:00 am".

However, when I read the file using R's `xlsx` package, the value becomes 41932-- class `factor`. How can I read the entire column as a string (as is)? I want to be the one to convert the date/time values into `POSIXlt` and/or `POSIXct` classes.

Comment: Please make a reproducible question if you really want help. Have a look of your answer is here, http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/xlsx/docs/read.xlsx and check this link for how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Using the `XLConnect` package addresses the issue. The column is read as it is as a string and is not converted into a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read into string with Hadley's [`readxl`](https://github.com/hadley/readxl/) package.

```
library(readxl)
df <- read_excel('~/Desktop/test.xlsx')
```

There is some support for `col_type` but it's not ready yet. Instead, you can use `as.POSIXct` to fix those after being read into a `data.frame`

e.g.

```
as.POSIXct(df$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz="CET")
```

Comment: Thank you, @Maiasaura, for the recommendation.